# Woocommerce - update variation id in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can update the quantity of the product in the cart, but how can I update the variation_id in the cart and variation array by cart_item_key?

My custom cart page has 2 fields for changing color and size on the cart page. 
I can get variation_id from the color and size attributes, but I cannot update this variables in the cart. I did not find such a function or solution. I can delete this product and add it again with the desired variation_id, but I think that this is not the right solution.

Comment: Did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps but I used a combination of things.

I added a custom variation form in each cart item, if that variation change, I trigger `WC()->cart->remove_cart_item()` and then `WC()->cart->add_to_cart()`, as you can see on the reference it returns an $cart_item_key.

I removed the cart item and added a new one with the new info. With javascript it can be showed to the user like nothing happened

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html#method_remove_cart_item

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html#method_add_to_cart